# asp net core mvc create instance controller System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I fix this issue `System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'`
I followed this code from codeproject
[CodeProject Code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1130342/Best-ways-of-implementing-Uniqueness-or-Unique-Key).

Already tried adding blank constructor in Controller but it's giving me another error. `InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type 'SlhSd18.Controllers.FunctionsController'. There should only be one applicable constructor.`

Here is my model code:

```
    namespace SlhSd18.Models
{
    public class Function
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(10)]
        [CustomRemoteValidation("IsFunctionIdExist", "Functions", AdditionalFields = "Id",
            ErrorMessage = "Function Id already exist.")]
        public string FunctionId { get; set; }
```

Controller Code:

```
    namespace SlhSd18.Controllers
{
    public class FunctionsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SlhSd18Context _context;

        public FunctionsController(SlhSd18Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult IsFunctionIdExist(string functionId, int ? Id)
        {
            bool validate = _context.Function.Any
                (x => x.FunctionId == functionId && x.Id != Id);

            if (validate ==true)
            {
                return Json(false);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(true);
            }
        }
```

CustomRemoteValidation Code:
[image]

SlhSd18 Class Code

```
    namespace SlhSd18.Models
{
    public class SlhSd18Context : DbContext
    {
        public SlhSd18Context (DbContextOptions<SlhSd18Context> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<SlhSd18.Models.Movie> Movie { get; set; }

        public DbSet<SlhSd18.Models.ChartofAccount> ChartofAccount { get; set; }

        public DbSet<SlhSd18.Models.Function> Function { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: "Already tried adding blank constructor in Controller but it's giving me another error." And that error is...? How do you expect the infrastructure to provide a `SlhSd18Context`? Do you have that configured anywhere in your dependency injection part?

Comment: @JonSkeet InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type 'SlhSd18.Controllers.FunctionsController'. There should only be one applicable constructor.

Comment: Right - please edit that into your question. (*Every* time a question refers to an error, it should specify what that error is.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, copy. thanks

Comment: what the code inside SlhSd18Context  class?

Comment: Where does your second error come from? Is it also from the call to `CreateInstance`? I expect that it isn't - more likely, it's coming from the DI system as it tries to create a controller for you. Your call to `CreateInstance` isn't going to use the DI system and so it's not going to be able to pass any dependencies through.

Comment: @Gauravshukla, updated post. thanks

Comment: @KirkLarkin, From Views, Index.cshtml

Comment: Unfortunately, the code quality in that CodeProject article you linked is very poor. The main issue you are having is that it is using `Activator.CreateInstance` to instantiate the controller, making that approach incompatible with dependency injection. I suggest you have a look at the official [Remote Validation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#remote-validation) from Microsoft which uses a better approach.

Comment: i also faced this problem before i think the problem is with SlhSd18Context  class, make sure that every thing is working fine in this class like connection establishment and all.
you can found the same here. may be you forget to add it in startup file
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt703433.aspx

Comment: CodeProject, almost without exception, sucks. The only people posting articles there are devs that don't know their butts from hot rocks. Avoid it like the plague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know setup of your DI, but I suggest to use this method to create controller instance:

```
private object TryCreateController(ValidationContext context, string controllerName) {
    Type controllerType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Single(x => x.Name.ToString().ToLower() == controllerName+"Controller");
    if (controllerType == null) {
        return null;
    }
    foreach (var constructor in controllerType.GetConstructors()) {
        var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
        var args = new dynamic[parameters.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++) {
            args[i] = context.GetService(parameters[i].ParameterType);
        }

        try {
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType, args);
            if (instance != null) {
                return instance;
            }
        }
        catch {
            continue;
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

And you can change the highlighted line to the next:

```
object instance = TryCreateController(validationContext, this.RouteData["controller"].ToString().ToLower());
```